# python pdb not giving correct trace on exceptions

Tags: python, debugging

On my iMac, the debugger, running a faulty python script (on MAC OS Sierra), always points to the first active line of code as cause of an exception, while when launching without debugger the correct line is identified. Does anybody have an idea why this may occur and how to fix it?

Here's a simple example with a "File not found" exception:

The script exception_test.py:

```
1  # Some dummy lines...
2  a=1
3  b=2
4  c=a+b
5  # Lines casuing the exception:
6  with open("filename","r") as fid:
7      lines=fid.readlines()
```

When run without debugger, as in `python exception_test.py` it yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open("filename","r") as fid:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename'
```

identifying the correct line, i.e. line6,
while `python -m pdb exception_test.py` and successive `c` to continue yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1314, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1233, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 400, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "exception_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    a=1
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename'
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
```

indicating the first active line of code, i.e. line 2.

Comment: whats the name of your python source code file ?

Comment: exception_test.py

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely an issue of cpython and pdb, not your code, pypy could print correct traceback line number.

the `line_no` of the `frame` where the exception occurred is not right under `-m pdb`.

after some guessing and tracing, I could narrow to [this path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/bdb.py#L396):

```
sys.settrace(self.trace_dispatch)
    -> trace_dispatch() -> dispatch_line() -> user_line() -> interaction()
```

the real root cause is still not clear.